# Python 3.8 assignment/named expression syntax

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3.8.0rc1.
What is the logic behind the different syntax?

```
#I can write:
[ y:=i for i in range(5) ]
#and 
( y:=i for i in range(5) )

#but not
{ y:=i for i in range(5) }
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

#It must be:
{ (y:=i) for i in range(5) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the Python implementation. From the Python documentation, both list and set displays should behave identical when used with a comprehension.

Quote from https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html, emphasis mine:

> 6.2.5. List displays
>
> A list display is a possibly empty series of expressions enclosed in square brackets:
>
> list_display ::=  "[" [starred_list | comprehension] "]"
>
> A list display yields a new list object, the contents being specified by either a list of expressions or a comprehension. When a comma-separated list of expressions is supplied, its elements are evaluated from left to right and placed into the list object in that order. **When a comprehension is supplied, the list is constructed from the elements resulting from the comprehension.**
>
> 6.2.6. Set displays
>
> A set display is denoted by curly braces and distinguishable from dictionary displays by the lack of colons separating keys and values:
>
> set_display ::=  "{" (starred_list | comprehension) "}"
>
> A set display yields a new mutable set object, the contents being specified by either a sequence of expressions or a comprehension. When a comma-separated list of expressions is supplied, its elements are evaluated from left to right and added to the set object. **When a comprehension is supplied, the set is constructed from the elements resulting from the comprehension.**
>
> An empty set cannot be constructed with {}; this literal constructs an empty dictionary.